# native-base dynamically set button property?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add `bordered` property to the button element, how can I do that?

So I need to switch from `<Button>` to `<Button bordered>`. Any way to do this without assigning an entire `<Button><Text>I'm a button</Text></Button>` to a variable, then duplicating the same but with `bordered`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use true or false based on your selection. Store its value in state and when you do some operation set it to true. This is how your `Button` will look.

```
<Button bordered={this.state.isBordered}><Text>I'm a button</Text></Button>
```

whenever you want to change its value just use `setState` and it's done

```
this.setState({
    isBordered:true
})
```

**Update:**

Combine it with `transparent` parameter and it will work

```
<Button transparent bordered={this.state.isBordered}><Text>I'm a button</Text></Button>
```

Comment: it doesn't look like native-base has this as a boolean property. Using either true or false keeps the button at it's default appearance.

Comment: But it is working perfectly with my live project. That is why i have posted it as an answer, i know it not boolean parameter but still using true/false it is working fine for me

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@haosmark/simple-app here is a snack, it isn't working here either. Can you change it to a working example?

Comment: Combine it with `transparent` parameter also, check my updated answer